# Overwrite via git stash apply

Tags: git, git-stash, git-merge-conflict

I am having a merge conflict when using `git stash apply`.  How can I hard overwrite files using stash?
Something like that

```
git stash apply -Xours
```

Comment: Please take look at this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16606203/force-git-stash-to-overwrite-added-files

Comment: Try committing first?

Comment: I would suggest that this is one of many reasons for not using stash.

Answer (score 3):

For the time being, `git stash pop` and `git stash apply` don't offer a way to automatically resolve conflicts.

From the documentation of [`git stash pop`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt-pop--index-q--quietltstashgt):

> Applying the state can fail with conflicts; in this case, it is not removed from the stash list. You need to resolve the conflicts by hand and call `git stash drop` manually afterwards.

What you can do, however, is use `git checkout` to quickly resolve the conflicts by choosing one side.

Here's a bit from the [Git Book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Advanced-Merging#_checking_out_conflicts):

> The `git checkout` command can also take `--ours` and `--theirs` options, which can be a really fast way of just choosing either one side or the other without merging things at all.

In your case, you can simply run this after `git stash apply`:

```sh
git checkout --ours -- /path/to/conflicting/file
```